# Firefox perhaps having trouble with stackexchange and possibly making too many requests

Tags: firefox, 18.04, chromium, browser, firefox-extensions

Does Firefox have trouble with Stackoverflow?

[image: ff]

It fixes itself pretty quickly.  I have a slow connection.

Went [ahead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310849/177328) and installed `chromium-browser`.  Chrome seems a **bit** better, but not hugely.  System:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 60.0.1
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: Maybe you have some ad/script blocker running?

Comment: "It fixes itself pretty quickly. I have a slow connection." I think that's it really. There possibly may be something else, but when my internet speede slows down I see it too on sites like youtube. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This is normal. It happens because your browser loads the text content (html) of a page before the styling (css). When the styling has finished loading, the page gets updated.

Comment: @DKBose only dark reader.  I'll check.  If it persists I'll try a safe mode for FF.  consensus seems to be that this is expected from FF.

Comment: If you go to the network tab in Web Developer Tools, you can see the order elements are loading. Slowness will be obvious.